# AWS API Call with Authorization Header ( session.getIdToken().getJwtToken() )

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, session, amazon-cognito

I Have a WebPage That USE AWS API Gateway using AWS-Cognito Authentication. Most of the Buttons in Web Page Call Api and send or Retrieve data. This is the Code I Use Under Every Button Click

```
getAuthenticateUser().getSession(function(err,session){
     if (err) {
        console.log("Error"+err);
        return;
    }
    if(session.isValid())
    {

    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        headers:
      {
            'Authorization':session.getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
            'Content-Type':'application/json'

        },
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data){

                // Execute Function Need to Execute on Success
        }


        ,
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {


                console.log(errorThrown);


            }
      });

    }
    if(!session.isValid())
    {
        console.log("Session is not valid..!");
         //Please Login to Continue
    }

    });
```

This is Working Fine without Issue.But the Problem is It take Some Time to Execute it Everytime and Feeles like every time it Gives a New Session for Each call even Previous Session is not Expired. How can I Use get new Session Only when it Expired and if Previous Session is not Expired just check the validity of it globally and get a new Authorization Header Only I need..?

Because In My Code Once User Press One Button and Send Data id same User press another button after 30 sec i'm getting new session again right ..? it really gives me really bad on web site Performance.

Any Idea How to Solve this ..?

this my getAuthenticationUser() Code

```
function getAuthenticateUser()
{

  return userPool.getCurrentUser();
}
```

and this my Global Variable in that Javascript page

```
    var poolData = {
                    UserPoolId : 'usXXXXXXXXXXOv3jSL',
                    ClientId : 'XXXXXXXXXXka8g'
                 };
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSession()` does not create a new session if the current session is valid.

If the current session is either null or invalid, it tries to refresh the session (using the refresh token) to get the ID token that is necessary to successfully complete the HTTP request using the `Authorization` header. Otherwise, it throws an error requesting to authenticate.

You can see what `getSession()` exactly does by taking a look at the [CognitoUser](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/master/src/CognitoUser.js) class definition. (currently on line 1016.)

Comment: Thank you..! So You think This is the right way to do it ..? or is their any Other thing to do to increase Performance ..?

Comment: I don't believe there is any other way to do it since you'll have to check the validity of the session's ID token before *each* ajax request. In terms of performance, there would be a minimal penalty of course if the session becomes invalid.